# A Process is started but it is blocked from reading another file

Tags: c#, r, permissions

I use `C#` to write a program in which I need to create a `R` engine and let it run another `R` script file. Therefore I need to start a process, e.g. `Rscript.exe` or `rcmd.exe`, and give it an argument that specifies the `R` code file to run.

The problem is, the `R` engine is successfully executed, but it seems not to have access to the `R` script file, no matter where it is located (e.g. directly in Documents, or `E:\a.r`, etc.).

My program is running under Admin permission.

How can I make it work?

Comment: Could you show us the lines in R you use to read the file, e.g. `read.table(commandArgs()[3]...` and what R does to report lack of access (an error message?)

Comment: In addition to the previous comment, check if everything works fine is you call Rscript directly (i.e. from the terminal).

Comment: The R code is simple (just one line): `writeChar(getwd(),"e:/temp/a.log")` in which the necessary folder exists and it works with rscript.exe directly called in Run or cmd. The error message of Rscript is "access denied: e:/".

Comment: You might have another process that has the file opened with a lock (e.g. excel..)

Comment: For these sorts of issues, SysInternals Process Monitor and Process Explorer are your friends.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb842062.aspx
in particular:
Process Explorer: Ctrl-F, search for processes with handle to file
Process Monitor: observe accesses to files.